# How to prevent event-bubbling from a textarea while keeping it editable?

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, jquery-events

I have a listview in jQuery mobile where each entry contains several lines of text.

Clicking on the entry is supposed to replace some parts of the text with a <textarea> to make it editable. Clicking on the entry again should again replace the textarea with plain text (now edited).

While editing the text, the user should be able to click around within the textbox to select parts of the text or move the cursor around. To prevent click events from the textarea from bubbling, I use `stopPropagation()` on the event and that works quite nicely.

**However, while this works in Chrome & Safari, both Firefox and Internet Explorer do not move the cursor nor let the user select parts of the text within the textarea.**

Is there something I am missing here? (For Firefox, I am using version 19.0.2 on Windows 7, if that is relevant. I have tried using preventDefault or returning false, but that did not work - and why should it?)

I have created a [JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/7AvdX/6/)

The html code is

```
<ul id="listid" data-role="listview" data-filter="true" data-iconpos="center" data-split-icon="arrow-u" data-theme="c" data-split-theme="b" data-inset="true">
<li><a href="#" id="link1">
  <h2>Title</h2>
  <p>Here is some item<br />with several lines<br />
    <span id="comment1">And this line is supposed to be editable</span>
    <textarea style='display: none; width: 95%;' id="textarea1"></textarea>
   </p></a>
  <a href="#" onclick="alert('Something else happens here')">This does something else</a>
</li>
</ul>
```

and the respective JavaScript is (loaded on body.onLoad here, but that is just for the JsFiddle):

```
window.toggled = false;

$("#link1").click( function(e){
    var textarea = $("#textarea1").toggle();
    var comment =  $("#comment1").toggle();
    if(window.toggled){
        comment.html(textarea.val());
    }
    else{
       textarea.val(comment.html());
    }
    toggled = !toggled;
});

$("#textarea1").click(function(e){
    if(console && console.log){ console.log(e);}
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Please ignore the not-quite-so-elegant solution for toggling the textarea.

Answer (score 0):

IE is not happy with the textarea inside an anchor tag. See http://jsfiddle.net/zCfRu/

```
<a href="#" id="link1"> 
<h2>Title</h2>
<p>Here is some item<br />with several lines<br />
<span id="comment1">And this line is supposed to be editable</span>
</p>
</a>
<textarea style='display: none; width: 95%;' id="textarea1"></textarea>
```